# How to collapse one dataset to get incremental instances in a new dataset?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to collapse one dataframe that has the following unit of analysis: country-pta-yea into country-year. I tried group_by and summarise but it would sum up all the values instead of incrementally adding them as each observation of "value" is present for each PTA in different years. Below is the dataframe (df) I have and the dataframe I would like to achieve (df2).

What should I do next?

```
country <- c("USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA")
year <- c(2000,2001,2002,2000,2001,2002)
pta <- c("a","a","a","y","y","y")
value <- c(0,1,1,0,0,1)

df <- data.frame(country, year,pta, value)

country1 <- c("USA","USA","USA")
year1 <- c(2000,2001,2002)
value1 <- c(0,1,2)

df2 <- data.frame(country1,year1, value1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a group by `sum` i.e. grouped by 'country', 'year', get the `sum` of value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(country, year) %>% 
   summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: @ThaiTeasy Basedon your dataset, if I check the 'y' value, then the output is not the same as expected output

Comment: Also, how do I ignore NAs when summarising? I see in some other post that I would have to use summarise_all(funs(),na.rm=TRUE). I'm not trying to summarise everything, is there a way to integrate na.rm=TRUE in this function?

Comment: @ThaiTeasy just specify `sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)` updated